# Is it just for the CRA to charge interest on a notice of collection dated one month ago, but that they never mailed?

Tags: canada, canada-revenue-agency

My dad is old, computer-illiterate, and needs a wheelchair. On Feb. 20 2019, he received by mail the CRA's Notice of collection that "calculated additional arrears interest of $30" on "your notice of assessment."

He was puzzled as his "notice of assessment" didn't require any payment. On Mar. 8 2019, I set up his CRA account online to message them, until I saw a "Notice of reassessment" dated Jan. 9 2019. He never received this in the mail. We paid the balance + this $30 forthwith.

But this $30 interest feels a shade unjust, as:

1. the CRA failed to mail him the Jan. 9 Notice of Reassessment.
2. How's it just  for the CRA to charge  us for being one month late, when they can be late far more than one month without compensating taxpayers?
3. It's unreasonable to expect a taxpayer like my dad to check his CRA account weekly.
4. Is there any law that can help us request interest waiver? Or must our request depend wholly on the CRA's goodwill and warmheartedness? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just? Of course not. But government has never been about justice.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a very sympathetic letter to the CRA explaining your circumstances, with a specific request to waive the interest on non-payment, with proof that payment of the balance owing has already been made,they may decide to waive the interest charged. If they fail to waive it... I recommend you pay the $30. Unjust or not, you have to ask yourself how much of your time is worth $30. Fighting the CRA can be excruciating, regardless of whether you are 'right' to do so.

Per your exact question, your success will depend on "#4 - the particular CRA agent's goodwill and warmheartedness".